# Angular routeProvider Resolve not called

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have a simple resolve function set up in my route provider.  Something like

```
.config(['$routeProvider', 'Constants', function config($routeProvider, Constants) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('mypage', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/mypage.tpl.html',
            controller: 'MyPageCtrl',
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            resolve: {
                factory: 'MyPageResolve'
            }
        })
)];
```

Where that factory is declared in a module like this:

```
.factory('MyPageResolve', ['$q', '$log', 'someAPI',
    function ($q, $log, someAPI) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var postUserFunc = function () {

            someAPI.get(
                function(data, status) { //$http.get().success() func
                    defer.resolve();
                }
            );

        };
        return defer.promise;
}]);
```

What's happening is on straight refresh or on the first load, this resolve method is hit.  However, if I have a $location.url('/mypage'); change from one route to this one, angular is not re-resolving this controller.

I might be not thinking of resolve in the right way, and if so, would take recommendations on the 'angular' way to do this.  I would like all this information loaded before the view, and is variable based on the route params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ends up I needed to make that factory into just a function.  A factory acts as a singleton, so it will only run once.

So I made my factory look like:

```
var myPageResolve = ['$q', '$log', 'someAPI',
function ($q, $log, someAPI) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var postUserFunc = function () {

        someAPI.get(
            function(data, status) { //$http.get().success() func
                defer.resolve();
            }
        );

    };
    return defer.promise;
}]);
```

And instead of resolving on `'myPageResolve'`, I resolved on `myPageResolve`. Very subtle change made all the difference.